# Terraform aws_cloudfront_cache_policy pass multiple cookies to cookies_config

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I can't seem to pass multiple cookies in the "items" list when in "cookies_config -> cookies"

Here is my variable:

```
variable "cache_policy_defaults" {
    type = object({
        name = string
        comment = string
        default_ttl = number
        max_ttl = number
        min_ttl = number
        cookie_behavior = string
        cookies_to_forward = optional(list(string))
        header_behavior = string
        headers_to_forward = optional(list(string))
        query_string_behavior = string
        query_strings_to_forward = optional(list(string))
    }
    )
    default = {
        name = ""
        comment = ""
        default_ttl = 60
        max_ttl = 60
        min_ttl = 60
        cookie_behavior = "none"
        cookies_to_forward = []
        header_behavior = "none"
        headers_to_forward = []
        query_string_behavior = "none"
        query_strings_to_forward = []
    }
}
```

Here are my locals:

```
locals {
    origin_id = "origin_${local.origin_config.domain_name}"
    origin_config = merge(var.origin_defaults, var.origin_settings)
    restrictions = merge(var.restrictions_defaults, var.restrictions_settings)
    default_cache_behavior = merge(var.default_cache_behavior_defaults, var.default_cache_behavior_settings)
    cache_policy = merge(var.cache_policy_defaults, var.cache_policy_settings)
    cache_policy_name = "cache_policy_${var.name}"
}
```

Here is my tfvars:

```
"cache_policy_settings": {
        "min_ttl": 30,
        "max_ttl": 30,
        "default_ttl": 30,
        "cookie_behavior": "whitelist",
        "cookies_to_forward": ["123", "456"]
    }
```

Here is my main.tf:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_cache_policy" "this" {
  name        = lookup(local.cache_policy, local.cache_policy.name, local.cache_policy_name)
  comment     = local.cache_policy.comment
  default_ttl = local.cache_policy.default_ttl
  max_ttl     = local.cache_policy.max_ttl
  min_ttl     = local.cache_policy.min_ttl

  parameters_in_cache_key_and_forwarded_to_origin {
    cookies_config {
        cookie_behavior = local.cache_policy.cookie_behavior
        dynamic "cookies" {
            for_each = local.cache_policy.cookies_to_forward != null ? local.cache_policy.cookies_to_forward : null
            content {
                items = local.cache_policy.cookies_to_forward
            }
        }
      }
    headers_config {
        header_behavior = local.cache_policy.header_behavior
        dynamic "headers" {
            for_each = local.cache_policy.headers_to_forward != null ? local.cache_policy.headers_to_forward : null
            content {
                items = local.cache_policy.headers_to_forward
            }
        }
    }
    query_strings_config {
        query_string_behavior = local.cache_policy.query_string_behavior
        dynamic "query_strings" {
            for_each = local.cache_policy.query_strings_to_forward != null ? local.cache_policy.query_strings_to_forward : null
            content {
                items = local.cache_policy.query_strings_to_forward
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The docs state

> items: (Required) A list of item names (cookies, headers, or query strings).
> https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_cache_policy#items

However, the list does not accept multiple items.

```
Error: Too many list items

  on main.tf line 57, in resource "aws_cloudfront_cache_policy" "this":
  57:     cookies_config {

Attribute supports 1 item maximum, but config has 2 declared.
```

It seems that I should just be able to pass a list of items?  If I change the my input list to only contain a single value, then it works.

Comment: You haven't showed any of your local variables.

Comment: @Marcin Good catch.  I've updated the post with my locals.

Comment: Error is on `cookies_config {` line not `items =` line. So it can only have one cookies_config` and your dynamic/for_each is using your item list.

Comment: @JasonS I see what you're saying.  I'm newish to Terraform.  It's trying to create multiple cookies blocks and that's the error.  I'm trying to conditionally create the "cookies" block only if the list of cookies to forward is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the trick:

```
for_each = local.cache_policy.cookies_to_forward != null ? [1] : null
```

This tells Terraform to create exactly one block by making the true value of the ternary `[1]`.

Thanks Jason for putting me on the right track.